# Oracle, check a row for change then update incase of changes in data

Tags: oracle

I need to update a row in Oracle, but I dont know if the row already has latest data.
The best I could come up was doing a select like below cheking if it has latest data then updating incase it doesn't have latest data

```
     IF 1 != ( SELECT 1 FROM MY_TABLE WHERE COLUMN1 = UDATED_COLUMN1 AND COLUMN2 = UDATED_COLUMN2 AND COLUMN3 = UDATED_COLUMN3) THEN
        Merge INTO MY_TABLE 
            USING Dual
            ON ( COLUMN3 = UDATED_COLUMN3)
              WHEN matched THEN
                UPDATE
                SET COLUMN1 = UDATED_COLUMN1 AND COLUMN2 = UDATED_COLUMN2
              WHEN NOT matched THEN
                INSERT (COLUMN1 , COLUMN2,COLUMN3) VALUES (UDATED_COLUMN1 , UDATED_COLUMN2,UDATED_COLUMN3);
```

Is there any efficient way in dong this in a single operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `WHERE` clause to the `MERGE` and do not use the `IF` statement:

```sql
Merge INTO MY_TABLE 
USING Dual
ON ( COLUMN3 = UDATED_COLUMN3)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET COLUMN1 = UDATED_COLUMN1,
      COLUMN2 = UDATED_COLUMN2
  WHERE COLUMN1 <> UDATED_COLUMN1
  OR    COLUMN2 <> UDATED_COLUMN2
WHEN NOT matched THEN
  INSERT (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
  VALUES (UDATED_COLUMN1, UDATED_COLUMN2, UDATED_COLUMN3);
```

If you can have `NULL` column values then:

```sql
Merge INTO MY_TABLE 
USING Dual
ON (
   COLUMN3 = UDATED_COLUMN3
OR (COLUMN3 IS NULL AND UDATED_COLUMN3 IS NULL)
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET COLUMN1 = UDATED_COLUMN1,
      COLUMN2 = UDATED_COLUMN2
  WHERE COLUMN1 <> UDATED_COLUMN1
  OR    (COLUMN1 IS NULL AND UDATED_COLUMN1 IS NOT NULL)
  OR    (COLUMN1 IS NOT NULL AND UDATED_COLUMN1 IS NULL)
  OR    COLUMN2 <> UDATED_COLUMN2
  OR    (COLUMN2 IS NULL AND UDATED_COLUMN2 IS NOT NULL)
  OR    (COLUMN2 IS NOT NULL AND UDATED_COLUMN2 IS NULL)
WHEN NOT matched THEN
  INSERT (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
  VALUES (UDATED_COLUMN1, UDATED_COLUMN2, UDATED_COLUMN3);
```

Comment: in this case even if the data is same we are updating again right? its a huge table and will take performance hit.

Comment: @Ravi You are checking the table twice; once in the `SELECT` in the `IF` statement and once again in the `MERGE`; this is only a single statement and the row will only be updated if the `ON` and `WHERE` clauses match so it should reduce the number of changes to a minimum. If you are worried about performance then profile both solutions check for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `IF` and just `MERGE`, regardless.

That way `MY_TABLE` will always contain the latest data.

Yes, you'll sometimes unnecessary update the table, but - if it doesn't cost much (i.e. a table is "small", ...), why spending time on checking whether you should be doing anything? Just do it!

Comment: Made a small mistake in merge condition update it now. Table is huge , so updating all records will take a performance hit.